# Error with mysql2 gem loading Rails env on OSX: "Symbol not found: _rb_prohibit_interrupt"

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundle, mysql2

- I'm on OSX 10.7.5
- I'm setting up an existing Rails 3 app
- I've got the 64-bit dmg package of MySQL (v5.5.28) installed
- I've installed the mysql2 gem (v0.3.11) as part of the app bundle

Whenever i try to load the rails env (raking, loading console, etc.), I get this:
rake aborted!
dlopen(/Users/daretorant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@amp/bundler/gems/mysql2-f4d004ac5194/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle, 9): Symbol not found: _rb_prohibit_interrupt
  Referenced from: /Users/daretorant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@amp/bundler/gems/mysql2-f4d004ac5194/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Users/daretorant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@amp/bundler/gems/mysql2-f4d004ac5194/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle - /Users/daretorant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@amp/bundler/gems/mysql2-f4d004ac5194/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
/Users/daretorant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@amp/bundler/gems/mysql2-f4d004ac5194/lib/mysql2.rb:9:in `require'
/Users/daretorant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@amp/bundler/gems/mysql2-f4d004ac5194/lib/mysql2.rb:9:in`'

.........

Things I've tried:

- other versions of mysql2
- fresh install of mysql itself
- cleaning my gemset
- cleaning rvm
- pulling hair out

Help?

Comment: what I understand is that this might be due to 2 different version of ruby install. and causing conflicts. one version to do only ruby, and other to run rails.

Answer (score 0):

I have just run into this issue. What had helped me was installing the 64bit version of the `mysql2` gem, like this:

```
$ env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install mysql2
```